# PVS-Studio. Отслеживает ли CLMonitor.exe вызовы gcc.exe из состава Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

Во время компиляции open source утилиты  patch в среде Cygwin x64 как под контролем мониторинга PVS-Studio Standalone (лицензия PVS-Studio Free, комментарии типа №2 в исходные тексты вставлены), так и непосредственно CLMonitor.exe, утилита подсчитывает вызовы компилятора:

[image: Compiler invocations detected: 84]

но по завершении отслеживания ("Stop Monitoring" или "CLMonitor analyze ...") не находит файлов для анализа - "PVS-Studio was not able to detect any files for analyzis."

[image: "PVS-Studio was not able to detect any files for analyzis."]

При **выключенной** опции "Remove intermediate files" в каталогах создаются файлы *.env и *.log.
Файлы *.log содержат следующие записи:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\gcc.exe
T:\06_Tools\patch\src\
"C:\cygwin64\bin\gcc.exe"
"C:\cygwin64\bin\gcc.exe"
```

Хочется понять - это частная ошибка или Cygwin (x64) не поддерживается?

То есть - ждать ли исправления или переходить например на MinGW.

Comment: Я думаю, имеет смысл обратиться в поддержку PVS-Studio.

Comment: https://www.viva64.com/ru/b/0482/
"Поддержка пользователей, использующих бесплатную лицензию PVS-Studio, теперь осуществляется на сайте StackOverflow"

Comment: Я добавлю к вопросу метку pvs-studio, но думаю лучше продублировать вопрос на англоязычном stackoverflow, т.к. не факт что они мониторят ru.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Спасибо!
Я ещё в твиттере кинул им ссылку как раз с просьбой про метку :)

Comment: Все в порядке. Теперь метка существует (по крайней мере, некоторое время) и они смогут на нее подписаться :-)

Answer (score 2):

CLMonitor НЕ работает с компиляторами из состава Cygwin. Это связано с тем, что Cygwin передаёт параметры запуска процесса подобно подсистеме procfs на Linux, не как "обычные" параметры запуска, а через специальный файл, и CLMonitor не видит их.

Тем не менее, некоторые проекты можно проверять и в Cygwin. Часто для сборки кросс-платформенных проектов используются только утилиты из состава Cygwin, а в качестве компилятора MinGW или MSVC. Примером такого проекта является LibreOffice.

Также Вы можете воспользоваться Linux версией анализатора.

Если Вам важно работать в Windows, то можете попробовать воспользоваться подсистемой Linux, там анализатор тоже должен работать.

Comment: А cygwin разве не дублирует параметры запуска процесса в командной строке? Когда я последний раз смотрел их код - они всегда передавали их обоими способами, а уже запускаемый процесс выбирал откуда параметры брать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov возможно для всего, что не из состава Cygwin, параметры и дублируются, поэтому мониторинг работает для MinGW/MSVC.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, коллеги!

Comment: Святослав, а можете передать Евгению Рыжкову, что его статью "PVS-Studio теперь поддерживает любую сборочную систему на Windows и любой компилятор. Легко и "из коробки" (https://www.viva64.com/ru/b/0243/#ID0ESQAG ) нужно немного откорректировать...
.
Вот этот тезис теперь не выглядит абсолютно корректным:
.
` *О проблемах и ограничениях*
Каких-либо принципиальных проблем в технологии мониторинга мы (пока?) не выявили.`

Comment: Коллеги! А можете дать ссылку (или поисковый запрос) - что почитать по теме передачи параметров Cygwin'ом?

Comment: @РоманХвалибог "C:\cygwin64\bin\gcc.exe" не является Windows приложением, поэтому в статье всё корректно. И некоторая несовместимость с Cygwin/MSYS тоже.

Comment: @SvyatoslavRazmyslov Спасибо, я понял Вашу аргументацию.